# Mixed-effects logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models

I'm trying to make this mixed effects model with the following code:

```
f = read.csv2( file = "C:/Users/Customer/Desktop/R/language.csv", sep="," )

data = f[,c("wals_code", "X81A.Order.of.Subject..Object.and.Verb", 
"X87A.Order.of.Adjective.and.Noun", "family")]

data[data==""]<-NA

data<-data[complete.cases(data),]

data <- data[!data$X87A.Order.of.Adjective.and.Noun == "3 No dominant 
order", ]

data <- data[!data$X81A.Order.of.Subject..Object.and.Verb == "7 No dominant 
order", ]

View(data)

m <- glmer(X87A.Order.of.Adjective.and.Noun ~ 
X81A.Order.of.Subject..Object.and.Verb + family + (1|wals_code), data = 
data, family = binomial)
```

but i'm getting the following error :

Warning messages:

1: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations

2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient

3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues

Comment: Could you give an example of your data? Perhaps the issue may lie in the values being inappropriate for a logistic regression or the correlation structure between the gradient and intercept is too high for the convergence of the model (error 2 and 3). What errors (if any) do you get in a fixed effects glm?

Comment: the link to an image of how my data looks: https://imgur.com/5cgV7Aq

Comment: Have you tried fitting a regular logistic regression? I feel R doesn't like one of your variables and takes them as a numeric where you want a factor. Perhaps you could try to fit the model with just a partition of your data, maybe 30 data points and see if any errors pop up.